# ajax to get image from remote server

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I've hit a wall here. I don't know what I'm doing, bah!
I'm trying to us jquery ajax to request a gif image from a remote server.
I think its doing what it should be doing, but I have no idea where to go now that I got the data.
This is the function I'm using to get data from the server:

```
   function showGetResult(name){
         var result = null;
         var URL = name;
         $.ajax({
            url: URL,
            type: 'get',
            dataType: 'html',
            async: false,
            crossDomain: 'true',
            success: function(data, status) {
                console.log("Status: "+status+"\nData: "+data);
                result = data;
            } 
         });
         return result;
    };
```

When I get the gif image data it throws this at me...

> GIF87ad d � 
>   T�|F$��xtcS�Ǫ$��z   <.,dYT�~d��l��wted���TFDԴ����dO:TNC,%$L=5Ķ�4�~|�ʼ$�nTDFT���|eS�չ��s��v���tR<�n]LJCĨ��zdtn`\D2<><̰�d^VdRE�°$LbdlWD�ua�~p�zp���|vlLC;4%<2-\N<L2
>   tnl"$��jD>,,:$T>+�zY���D95,������4BLl~t��̌��435\\`���|�|���$,$\fldJL�¼t^?�δ���dbl���ĩ�tjeTJE0JD���L>+,:4���T>44:D<)���|ZD�~y�Ƭ�zhܾ��Ҽ̶�����n[�©D2-�z\�����|$"lbX��sD7+�����z4+$
>   lYU��l�vl���lR<4&$D0#\QL��~,��||^P4-,�����u̪�|oalRF��o���|oo$#$���lfd���dI<��t�j\DBD\VTdWL�sdtYDTE<ı�te\�ʴ���\FDԶ�L>D��|L9,,64�ztԾ�|f\���\F<̲�TfdlYLLFD\OD���42,���|jY\J;l^L*,D>:l^U,�zm>,|je\JD,
>   d d  � /�
>   ��a�.�@B�ڞx�1�A��hg�p.��c��2B@�"5N�a!*�q�b��k-�Ċ��F�Hh��P1SΞ1M�L��&
>   � Y*�ɢ̀�4\
>   �����V#�H��`v�SF�T�,�'֩eg��ɖm�>>!~�{�O7F$���S�O�l\;�C�/?��*���1&�M�b��4ZӼx!DH���' M��=&�b�<n�7V-�^�ʒ�����⃯�_���Hp��=�<_�cD��q����)K�o���9�-˼,\XUUyp�K1�`��
>   �Bp�� ����S<ڵ�\0��B�x�2&a��|�
>   {�b�M:��B�Tf�z�H`�;����=?�q�������U
>   �2���/�E_TTH-�QH�0(��@!r��]y����lc��p��1��O?��=�����8&����Pq�Ў/�,p�)M���1�5`U*h@�ń�!��\�{
>    FH�s�a��E���6M �&:ю6L�&�@�B�\�;�Ԏ�<������.��2�k�qL
>   d�U.�f�0S%R�!!���&!�$�9Qow�IW<{`B
>   qp�6�@FOc�X���N>2{��q�/b�AO��c�&��M;�d�-\���l/�
>   Á�"tѻ`"�C��P_͋]�Ņ���=�x�A����U�K��J�S;�#�b���67�VL�Ci�@������K�������&�&;������|8L-{x�
>   ��;:�B�4i4�2� ��F䃱����H&2�kq� {��Y��6Cm���W���0��.D7�S    �
>   ��Z�8����ao�T�;!Dn�*{�ю   ��'&�p �K1�pM�d-��  ڸ���3�
>   ܞ{l�z��b�.��  ~I�B ��5$�)]�E=�P�%.!����:��
>   ���9�qN|@0p�<��<��c�0!h�!?8B_�a
>   at�k���%����h!3\0����H@�#��h� �}1�.�H]��q�ax��X�
>   �p��@:D� .D��j�(��P+?� �a�d�WJ���)�� ��Y̘03&M
>   ��0H�$4���lƯxH�p�MG*� �a��8�Ae���1�`�G��01�
>   ���P�;���Zx�lP ^��f \���  It����`�+Br�(��lH�b�EZ�%!�
>   A�1�W#���A�0��50�03+8�S�}�_}@���ҡ�7xG;���)<�.��   1�ڜ���a0I$A�t�ͬ��u��A�<So�t��Qo,Gn
>   l��g �tЋ3CY�����_�� U0=�!��`G���L!�
>   &�L���V�IL�C1���M$p�)CܰN? �LF���T
>   ���p���ؘ�/Z�  m��`��� ���J6�^�?x��` � ����
>   UT���y�%�)�Ih�p�,�,��-�!�I��=�$�%��(@ V��'8�wpc��bюi�
>   &h�bqm��i��D-$>ԃ���$Α�>���BP7�%���@,��>�,��K<���a|!��Kl�<��]�������)����Z+x�����`�4Lb��PO̠��E>���!��C1n����P
>   *0 \t��MT"�0�e�Ŕ�����,: ��MLY]��X�@`�IL�� �ja�r� ���<� d���sT��~Ā��@.N��8��ʸ����`+������Aa&��ƚ��=�2�r����֨�X�
>   ��M�@��!u���0+6�� (c����a�#̀�G+ġ��B�80�3��J��E~a��)�ˠ.�Q4[D�l�B5~�
>   �XH�]��vV m��(�C1t!��aCɘ'���k�qМ  ����>�#���-�
>   UhP���6��TA5�Flgj+#   u}�^��&8�xJ�����6_�Lq@"����
>   ����&D�   5��$/�� !xC,聇}���F1�q�v��xw�Z0�3����F,� e�A]    U�`
>   �$�sf�F1,��.���˥����+���
>   �j��d�!`*��|�p�`�6T��!#�6`����T�{�8|Und���QlP]y��䁗�,�y�ȩ���I$����5��H�=|��He=���7V�P��a�A������)TJ�����1��    o�n�0
>   ��@�� %I1y�Ld@L�I��!9p~�:J��.q\��@{�� (� ���
>   ��|��p�`b�p@� ��M0T!Ӑg� :p
>   =�Lp �B@L�eu`7�R&3�P83�D= � ����`R��=n�p� ����    3�1��:�n@7����2b0��ܐ��� . �B�   :� bp50 S@Y�
>   �0W�}I0�0�y�2c3bJ� �@9�E!~R�:@W~@�����p�� �p(
>   �����S$k'�(3��Ő���2(��WB�� Jd
>   u�o�t��dؗ}`�t��IG��0XY���E/�D��� , Ѡ ܰ�$�� �Vn�A,
>   8���?@FP6����� b%�L��O��z]1   }�Hw��W2�c��4�l !?��
>   �h�V��,�SiA�pU�n� b�ipF�<�p�P ��uo���`���aNq\��_p��\�V`[`��H��XfL�hk9��>I��"�/4n
>   �8d@6pWPg�    �Pc�C[t{�,�p?������b&�� RP1�PK5�ʀ
>   }�D��W�4aN��h1b��u:3��Y��������pé
>   x0ڠ �t D�7!���D0?�&�)��}�@����   E7�}pR'!9�
>   �H�J  1�@!�L!��9�� �P.p<�Qڠ�p�4�P?x�`s BA�F@n@���� ��
>   j�L�C E�D�i)�Eg��W�_��z~� �$�a� _P,`]�tI$Иg��sg
>   |�Z��?p=��    �@� ���9,��0�1�� a#�pCV0Y0 ��� ����L��({
>   ]��(�}�व� q�֙JEG�~��0�������͐]�y(� oP��@?@��#�i���Еn�
>   �P${�G� �0�����D:�}��T�����   JEZ�`bzd !��`9�0P� ��\�� �
>   +p(�A�I�� �P�{��nP    �� ^ w��,��`�[���ɟ��� ����DE�P�X���
>   80� O��+  �/G �
>   ��p��Ve������:�={��`+n�2�"��P ,`���pi�[`4ɰ���ʊ�Y��Q����nP�hak�pe��x
>   �}��Zn@�0�Z�H �� ���� #:0_y�;��pM�U���4���}�������@���
>   �:��~ ���p�Z����0 H���%7�j�
>   RP�+�:T�P����To��j����ݩ p J
>   ���0F�Ⱥ�E'���y���<��Hp��ZP��#zp e�� 
>   0�SͰ8�P�J��~����9��0�b{|0� ��"j`�Y-�� {��0� ������@�
>   �F���8�pܻ�;�$�7���pP���
>   �<�����Ee�b�  �   �����g(�=�*�u#�p��b��p-P+ZP�� o
>   g��)0a�P�R��Pa�0"�%,�9@�~`��J��
>
> ## �A��+�h��7�V��~�0� �0ʰ��~��נd�*�? ?P j�����Q˰��*#�
>
> �/���uي� в��<�4E���$�}���(�I��7�Ѱn� ����  �P]����#�
>   |�������0���c�Sa���a� �!�ZI��c�!ɰ��7Pqp��� 70�e��
>   �@ �� �l9��P  b5�r e�HϽ�`@I�@aׇW�KI} � u��u�@~�]�LX�Z~ � 
>   x��}ܓ$�����%�\�P���;7�*z@�
>   ���7`�Fp-p&�P�PF0���%�����&mJ]4��y�Ev��t����!p�H
>   t��t@����0���p.��׀*� �P:�� ��bpky=�
>   �������R?����l��1�$�g,��q��I��8�`�{A������0J�u�7�Z�܀
>   k:d]��{]0�n�1&cq �!W`�`�\!����E�@��޵�ϚZ
>   n�""h-�~�x<���t�  �P��oPzh�a�^�KUQ� ZE����E�+�Q�� �P��
>   �` 4`�D�(��{o��[�+���r��}���t�U͠  �4���������vb��
>   �I �� Ѐ���O�@����C0R�\P P ����v@T������+O�~��G��| ���)�
>   � ����0� ��{n��(�ؼ ]�� +�Uq�PW��yP��p��ǠR(/� L@T@���
>   }P�q�! �� ��g9 +`г 9@F+@ɀ`��aPW��T�X�E�{� �`6`x@�`��
>   Vp� �~�q9 0p
>
> �J�y�;W"���Š������9���e؆��4  ����� � �F���
>   1��T|@�b�� ����&�S����9&��`P27�(adF���}�G0�
>   0.�Zp�����{��  +���|@inp 8ˁ\N :h�k�p�O\n&p#�P\���(����YV��Pސ`�`@4���h&�K=,N�惯e���X�G 
>   (`�`���е2��p��8�k�pb=��� �Y2Ӱ��������-Uv�@��Ub
>   FIsO�)�9X,��x|1���l�d@Ǜ����P(���C��C2�/�������G�ǐؐ��+��*�U0�R
>   5`���I�`2�x��!(`�U4�J��~�JS4�г ��� ���HԂ3��@~
>   %;r�U-    I����Ց$��5n�*O?�qk7�Xm6���&!M X/N��ť�0h���'&pHp���  ��
>   �#Gң�
>   $kF�jC?pn�iv1�;��u�Gb3`������Y3�9j��c�'U��؋3o_�~��86O1�������Dq��V�a�^���>�r�
>   Ǐ,2(
>   1D�,�4�)�'��j("�8r#�C��F�v�ZRs�6#-LL�����4.���b����R�����u��GB-�a,��
>   V--�p`��  ?<��+@B "�j�e#?&|W������� ��
>   �b�Azθ��,�`�,�)�+�a�I�e` ���H@����H�T`͏a
>   ���d�E-��".��hf��<L�B�.԰�a�&"?�k�7��A�w��G_ޙ�g�yԀ��b^P���(&�a�&B8�?�j��h&(N��.�#P
>   �
>   ����.�(L�b�^�t`�=p+w@r���G�}�H�4��p�C���h�#t�t8?n�(@
>   \Y*$��q��!C}� CA����^��jˁ�&~p�
>   ���   �v�y��&Fp��hA���p�  dYǏx��2
>   &�j�=��!Õx�q#5��Gގ$�������"#RK� S��)~������
>   7��%�y*��+*8%��p�=^��[2���V�e ? ����Y�Z.x
>   ��    �|�q^��[���Bô�ގ�!~@��V�P�[��3�Q�G1��x6"�
>   |Xл�V��J7B"f�T�/H�$��ʀ#�h��L�:,R�#��ʏd��ø��!*Z�!.n@�q���v�m����if�x���_G���J�S/$c�!��>LV���o�r��v�BK�U���Lh
>   �>�w�e�� . 2@���@)� 
>   *�HY3�4> c�" 萃�i�y$�F� *? !*���蒌� Dl�Y���E* �@�z P����È�]b!6`��7��'fpp�) ^@�B(%"7� 
>   *�2�#*��s YJ��H�B��dܠV:B2<�JT�V   yK�6d^0EeH�FGj�n��)F��8x�`��7p�ޠ�^���B;^Rc!X����d���be�Wԃ%�[-18�����D-I%���A.P�P�����w�b��_4�|A�A%�t!�A�
>   U-⑐����R!�yծ!Bj��#�3�B�C����/� B�r�^%�Lr�@�!��8D�=�cZ�(W�
>   9,�)5���fL�7������إH�҂��=��b����!*�
>   h��[r��1�gpqy�Qd���|KҖz��\�� �k�"R�z� G��E,b�U�hbn
>   �:4��̊zs�\�P�Z0i"��T+��D�n8K-�:L! ��[�t�� 1JtЛ+����i�
>   jQ��� ,~�^h�!��C-zG�k�"+@�FP�{^)��;�P 70D�|]��U���"CZ\
>   A��3J� �Ƃ7�m+����|(�X,`Q��Y�+H�m!B�u���%R]�V�K��
>   �;B�+FRwg�@�V��,r���[��DC�Vg�P>��OCB=" .�`�c
>   0y`�*@�Co8n-B����"D4,3�!(@Bo�s%m�����c��:Go"��0��x�g�pG-f�����(h�P��0P�@�P�?���-�G0��
>   �)�\@4~��*r�h|�@�>��sզ+h�R�܀t�Tz�t�B|���X-tP  ���BZd���=��/��]LBbL�PVP�
>   �L"i"���&b&�l�Â�Ɋ�A-��2$�,��&0j�����[�BB�w���0��5����-B)j`�>�BL����
>   M�7�~�����@�($�B�n`��f���D:`���.m�Mn~�����XC7hӪ[@��
>   {:0�0m��U��*���"P�Hyj��vA�+���2hY��*��T�ah� �@���l�-�D
>   �!/� $.���VR�D����P�R\�ٶ� ~��q�� &�E���9I��"� �+w#���
>   �h���M����D80�� ?_P������3�?�rC> ��8(�l��
>   n�Ab�*��F�1;�`���)Ra�`�!P`�2%����d��
>   ��d'��+�C�U7�m���U�����0  "�|�8j�P��kp�2��Z��h�h+
>   ���?(��yH\Ќ��`��`` �;p�#�Mh�=
>   �hY��ځ0@h�(Mx�ZH#���p8��J0�%�_�?�� �
>   3h8(58�����t�X8����7Plh�whfh�}��S؂��-��
>   ��a�7�H�cЂ2p�K�d���u��h$P�"�a7����#X8��+� K�;�
>   ��8�|hz`���8�@�m�X�t(�w�lP�S0� 0��U� Z�$x
>   ��p((�ɩ��I2M`0Ě��;�"B��b��=���)�C�v 
>   �Ʉ'�#0��jȅoІs�6��9�zp�W��"�mX�Z�0��N�zx��
>   p&8��c\p0��\���)� �����
>   �x�%���A��R�F�Ћ���3��7�8j�Zk�?��3(I>p����!@<z(@>^���@�
>   �e�C\�X�bx���0    ��8���0?B�#(�#�`Ѝ����F (�,h�z�
>   �Xh��"�J46Ȃ7���8�h�@.H    U{jU��#��8��>ȃU�](�y���X��v��x�@
>   �L��h@蒈d��� � ���A�N�I�w�  q��2���V "|p����mH��j{
>   �7x.P>{��~�j�_X�0��3X�b؂��}��qx�*�7�L�/
>     �H^�.�M�����4��^��I\�pH2��� ���f�E ^��;��%��}��ڃ.��
>   ��v�vh1�NX�2�+��,P ��x� ��(��1 �x
>   @.�tܜ��"�0I��i��k��?8
>   @UЁ���8+ ``a8#�1x�h���2�f&i�3�q�1p�S
>   �qH�~8�\�Qj@�h��8xL��|�z�)��)��@��x�4R���M
>   �=�l�5|�OY��
>   J8h��H�?��$�h��Є�Y�b��Jȁ0�I�j��&0�q���q0�6�J�����@�2(��  U0?�!�Pr�pȁ2�=��s���
>   �8�w(�J�L�|��#`w��bȂ3h�y �c�S��X:|�wP�S�ոF+�N�i�0�\xd4
>   �;hx�kxZ�+J/F���H����A�^��
>   18�ȇq�8�@mP{��!P���[�e��_؇JO���lq�
>   �1�0-h�k8n��?�0�%8�`X� �j���ȇ����;
>   ���H�VQ+r�J����m��PA��| �a�#�B`@w`�(&����
>   {�=8��#�X08����l�8���fh�th
>   m`�mA�K�����3؆v0�,P�I(��X��v�h�J��'�7h$@��)M�!@`�%)l��"i4O؃]hl(�7�,0�^��q��
>
> > ���_H^�a`�\�Myj8l��j�+P�_�@�?(�4���08bw�p��8�k��W�]!˦�PA@��1q��
> >     ��w�;mh�lȂ"��z�e��\x[
> >     ����eP�^���`�I�@�}x��m���&8�i8�i8���1x-��J�_hP|�|�`*��r�'
> >     -�9m����F ���ІH�}��7��,���z 8hO�&�O(�z��2h�/P�=�q�+r   ���Q��=�ib� 7�  "F���� J.��8k-[�h�4���N�^���
> >     �_H��1��[0U����7�nP.�pD��M� n8�A�-�)0z`�\ȅs8�y0�~�
> >     yNe�p�7xp�j돁
> >     �j��!h?���    �xq�f�H��K��WȂb��7��+h�����=��7��}�[@�w�qY$R��ymC�Xp    ��zh�[p�s�50�|@�݃
> >     $8���0�J���h  2H�ц�2&�WqQ�/`>�8�zh�,� ��֍e��\H�X�Ё�
> >     l���j����P0�H���1�G��[��c�,8���"t7" |�8�n��9�
> >     ���0�u ����xO� 1� <0J ȃ��h z��h�w�҆) � ?�2ɁX��wPI��X���
> >     l�d@1��� �zރ�  ;

What is this and what am I supposed to do with it??
Thx.

Comment: create div with any id append like this $('.div_image').html('<img src="data:image/png;base64,' + data + '" />'); this line should be in ajax success inside

Comment: @JYoThI it's a gif, not a png

Comment: Why are you using `async: false` ?

Comment: when you have image URL, why you need AJAX, just set it like $("#img-id").attr("src", URL); 
Or create a new element and append the container

Comment: I'm trying to make a plugin so I'm not using any html in my code, and I need the code to save the image to disk.

Comment: Why do you need AJAX to get the image file?

Comment: I'm still a noob with javascript, I'm not aware of any other ways to do what I want...

Comment: It'd be more far to just say I don't know. XD
I'm gasping at straws until the darn thing does what I want.

Answer (score 8):

```js
var data_received = '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';


/* PUT THIS INSIDE AJAX SUCCESS */
var img = $('<img id="image_id">');
img.attr('src', 'data:image/png;base64,' + data_received);
img.appendTo('#image_div');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="image_div">
  
</div>
```

**Not an answer but suggestion**. Why not get just the image url in ajax request ( in case image is hosted somewhere ) and use this url as `src` attribute in `img` tag.

```
 $.ajax({
        url: URL,
        type: 'get',
        dataType: 'html',
        async: false,
        crossDomain: 'true',
        success: function(data, status) {
            console.log("Status: "+status+"\nData: "+data);
            result = data;

            /* creating image assuming data is the url of image */
            var img = $('<img id="image_id">');
            img.attr('src', data);
            img.appendTo('#id_of_element_where_you_want_to_add_image'); 
        } 
});
```

Or if you are getting the encoded image in ajax response, you can use :

```
$.ajax({
        url: URL,
        type: 'get',
        dataType: 'html',
        async: false,
        crossDomain: 'true',
        success: function(data, status) {
            console.log("Status: "+status+"\nData: "+data);
            result = data;

            /* creating image */
            var img = $('<img id="image_id">');
            img.attr('src', 'data:image/gif;base64,' + data);
            img.appendTo('#id_of_element_where_you_want_to_add_image'); 
        } 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code for various photo format just replace png as gif, jpeg (Just Change url only and copy paste the code)

First generate the raw base64 then convert into image get base64 raw data of image from responseBody using jquery ajax

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "imageURL",
    beforeSend: function (xhr) {
        xhr.overrideMimeType('text/plain; charset=x-user-defined');
    },
    success: function (result, textStatus, jqXHR) {       
        if(result.length < 1){
            alert("The thumbnail doesn't exist");
            $("#thumbnail").attr("src", "data:image/png;base64,");
            return
        }

        var binary = "";
        var responseText = jqXHR.responseText;
        var responseTextLen = responseText.length;

        for ( i = 0; i < responseTextLen; i++ ) {
            binary += String.fromCharCode(responseText.charCodeAt(i) & 255)
        }
        $("#thumbnail").attr("src", "data:image/png;base64,"+);

        /* PUT THIS INSIDE AJAX SUCCESS */
        var img = $('<img id="image_id">');
        img.attr('src', 'data:image/png;base64,' + btoa(binary));
        img.appendTo('#image_div');
    },
    error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown){
        alert("Error in getting document "+textStatus);
    } 
});
```

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="image_div"></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Add the line below to the Php file

```
header("Content-Type: image/jpeg");
```