# How to fetch object from aws s3 using ajax get rest api

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a file named **3514706-ironmanvr-promo-nologo.jpg** in my s3 bucket and I am trying to download the file using javascript rest api, here is my code

```
var jqxhr = $.ajax({
            url: "https://s3.amazonaws.com/asif.test/3514706-ironmanvr-promo-nologo.jpg",
            type: "GET",
            async: true
        })
            .done(function (data, textStatus, jqXhr) {
               console.log(data);

            })
            .fail(function (jqXhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.log(errorThrown);
                if (errorThrown === "abort") {
                    alert("Uploading was aborted");
                } else {
                    alert("Uploading failed");
                }
            })
            .always(function (data, textStatus, jqXhr) { });
```

but in data I am getting garbage values like this

[response image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ro1Au.png)

I don't know how to deal with this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ajax to get image from remote server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40354638/ajax-to-get-image-from-remote-server)

Comment: No it does not @Bik

Answer (score 0):

I was having the exact same issue, and after much digging and hair-removal I came across this answer:

https://medium.com/@timleland/set-image-src-from-amazon-s3-2232d246bebd

It solved it for me; the article says:

"Since Jquery ajax does not support the responseType: ‘blob’, you have to set the value in the xhrFields. The other important part is to use window.URL.createObjectURL to convert the blob to a url for the image src."

```js
var loadImage = function (imageUrl) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: imageUrl,
        dataType: null,
        data: null,
        xhrFields: {
            responseType: 'blob'
        },
        success: function (imageData) {
            var blobUrl = window.URL.createObjectURL(imageData);
            $('#image-id').attr('src', blobUrl);
        }
    });  
};
```