# How to refresh a DIV dynamically in PHP

Tags: python, php, html, session

I am executing a Python file, that saves images to folders called 'latestimage.png' to a folder, in a PHP web page using this:

```
$proc = popen('python -u python.py', 'r');
                    echo '<pre>';
                    while (!feof($proc))
                        {
                            echo fread($proc, 4096);
                        }
                    echo '</pre>';
            }
```

As you can see there is a while loop that stops anything else from happening until the script is finished executing. I have a DIV that shows the latest version of 'latestimage.png':

```
<?php
                $filepath = $_SESSION['filepath'];
                $new_file = $filepath ."\\latestimage.png";
                ?>
                <img src="<?php echo $new_file; ?>">            
        </div>
```

I want to know how to dynamically update the DIV so that every time the Python file creates a new image, the DIV is updated to show the new image. Thanks.

Comment: Looks like you're gonna' need to learn AJAX.

Comment: do you want to click a button to get the latest image or  every few seconds check the img & get the latest img

Answer (score 0):

Since  is part of HTML and HTML is only looked at on the client-side you going to need to use something like AJAX that will request the image from the server for you just given the URL of it. You will have to do this every so often so you know that you are getting the latest version of the photo

Comment: Do you know what I would need to do in AJAX to accomplish my task?

Comment: Yeah see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40354638/ajax-to-get-image-from-remote-server just underneath the code snippet there is an example on how to use

Answer (score -1):

try  this

```
<?php
$filepath = $_SESSION['filepath'];
$new_file = $filepath ."\\latestimage.png";
if (isset($_GET['GetIMG'])&& $_GET['GetIMG']==1){
echo$new_file;
}else{
?>
<img id="IMG"src="<?php echo $new_file; ?>"> 

<script>
function GetIMG() 
{
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () 
  {

 if (xhttp.readyState === 4 && xhttp.status === 200)
 {
   document.getElementById("IMG").src = xhttp.responseText;

    }
  };

  xhttp.open("GET", "getIMG.php?GetIMG=1", true);
  xhttp.send();
}

intrv01 = window.setInterval(GetIMG, 5000); 

</script>


<?}?>
```

Comment: Unfortunately not. I'm not sure if it is what you are doing already, but I thought you would need to refresh the DIV every, for example, 10 seconds for the newest version of 'latestimage.png' to be shown instead of the older one.

Comment: Hi  pls  change the  `getIMG.php`  to your php page name  ✌

Comment: this code sends a request  to the same php page  to get the  url you put inside src property of the image tag  every 5seconds

Comment: I changed the page name and still no luck. Whenever I go to the getIMG.php?GetIMG=1 URL, the latest image does show so I think it is just a case of getting it to automatically go there. However, that would involve refreshing the whole page, but I just want to refresh the DIV with the image in.

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by does my code show the image? The image is in a folder.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208447/discussion-between-rkv88-kanyan-and-mine-craftian).