# HTML/Javascript How to display an image on a web application after uploading it?

Tags: javascript, html, function

currently have this in my html where the input type = text and I bring in an image via the url but i want to be able to change this to file or image and upload an image and display that image on a web application currently my function doesnt support this does anyone know how I could accomplish this? (im fairly new to javascript btw) obvs: I dont want to store anything on the backend I just want to upload an image and have it previewed on my web application

**HTML**

```
<body>
    <div id="backdrop"></div>
    <div class="modal" id="add-modal">
      <div class="modal__content">
        <label for="title">Tooling ID</label>
        <input type="text" name="title" id="title" />
        <label for="image-upload">Image Upload</label>
        <input type="text"  id="image-upload" name="image-upload"/>
        <label for="severity">Severity Rating</label>
        <input
          type="number"
          step="1"
          max="10"
          min="1"
          name="severity"
          id="severity"
        />
      </div>

**Javascript**
const renderNewIssueElement = (id, title, imageUpload, severity) => {
  const newIssueElement = document.createElement('li');
  newIssueElement.className = 'issue-element';
  newIssueElement.innerHTML = `
    <div class="issue-element__image">
      <img src="${imageUpload}" alt="${title}">
    </div>
    <div class="issue-element__info">
      <h2>${title}</h2>
      <p>${severity}/10 severity</p>
    </div>
  `;
  newIssueElement.addEventListener(
    'click',
    startDeleteIssueHandler.bind(null, id)
  );
  const listRoot = document.getElementById('issue-list');
  listRoot.append(newIssueElement);
};
```

[this is how the application currently looks like with a url image attachment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JiNQ1.png)

Comment: Hi, do you have any kind of backend code to handle where the image upload gets saved?  You can't do this all from front end javascript.  You have to have some network side code that handles saving the file and returning where it should be referenced from.

Comment: no im not running any network side code this project was built purely on javascript, css and html

Comment: i dont need to save anything on the backend i just need to display my uploaded image on the card

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) using native JavaScript, or

With [ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40354638/ajax-to-get-image-from-remote-server) using Jquery

Comment: there is no server side code im not trying to store or recieve from there im currently using my local to fetch and image from a folder and upload it once it is uploaded the image should be previewed on my web application

Comment: Basically, this is exactly the same http request, as you do when requesting a page html. You do serve your picture anyway (with nginx or apache web server), because you are able to download it withing the page. So, you don't have to modify your server side. All you need is to download your image with XMLHttpRequest after DOM is ready and paste it to your DOM, instead of adding image directly to the html.